# Can I target Blackberry HTML input fields to increase their height?

Tags: css, forms, blackberry

Is it possible to specifically target the Blackberry browser via css to resolve the hidden text issue in the image below?

[image]

The following css is currently applied:

```
input.searchfield {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    color: #666666;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to target Blackberry's proprietary browser using CSS alone.

A few things that might work:

- Use something like Eric Meyer's reset.css to reset browser defaults
- Set a font size, line-height and some padding to the field's CSS
- If neither of the above help, set a minimum height

Remember, the webkit declarations above won't be understood by Blackberry's browser.

It's difficult to get form fields to render consistently across multiple platforms to I wouldn't beat myself up over not having everything exactly the same on each.